# How do I create a line between each column in ListView in C# WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, line

Since my English is not very good, I want to explain with screenshots.
Default ListView = https://prnt.sc/ToV27-crYWKI
What i want = https://prnt.sc/k8Iw4BY6CmtF
The places I have drawn in red do not need to be red. I want a thin line with low opacity.

Since I don't know enough about using WPF, I couldn't try much.

Comment: Use a datagrid. https://wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

you need to add data template  in list view detail and design as it has border, after that you need give border thickness only on right side. and give it colour and Opacity.

```
<ListView AlternationCount="2"
      Style="{DynamicResource SubstituteLinkProductListViewStyle}"
      SelectionMode="Single"
      ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource NewActivePromotionRegionListViewItemStyle}"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=lstXyz, Mode=TwoWay}">
     <ListView.View>
         <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{DynamicResource CloseRegisterRegionListGridViewHeaderStyle}"  >
             <GridView.Columns>
                 <GridViewColumn Width="150"  >
                     <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Status" />
                     <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                            <Border BorderThickness="0 0 5 0" BorderBrush="Red" >
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                           FontFamily="Roboto"  FontSize="12"
                                          Text="{Binding ABC}" >
                                          </TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                 </GridViewColumn>
             </GridView.Columns>
         </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
```